# Extract "x" amount of characters before keyword RegExp (BigQuery)

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am new to regexp and BQ and I am trying to extract the intervals before a keyword in this case "Years". The string is: "1-10 Years, 2 to 4 Years | 6-9 Years. 3-4 Years"

The objective is to identify the intervals: "1-10", "2 to 4", "6-9" and "3-4"

I did some research and tried something like this:

```
WITH example AS (
SELECT
"1-10 Years, 2 to 4 Years | 6-9 Years. 3-4 Years" AS name
)
SELECT SUBSTR(name,(pos-4),8) AS Result FROM (
SELECT 
name,
LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT(LOWER(name), r'^(.*)years.*')) + 1 AS pos
from example
)
```

But I only identify the last interval ("3-4") and if the character length of that interval is different is not going to do a good work either. So I was wondering if there is a way to identify these intervals in the string. Thanks if you take the time lo leave a comment.

Comment: Could you match `(\d+\D+\d+) +Years\b`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c83vbb/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select name, 
  regexp_extract_all(name, r'[^\d- ]*([\d- to]*) Years') result_as_array,
  array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(name, r'[^\d- ]*([\d- to]*) Years'), ', ') result_as_string
from example
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Please reconsider your regex. If the string were `"New Years doot 4 Years $-^ Years"`, it would match `"New Years"` (Group 1 empty), `"doot 4 Years"` (Group 1 `" 4"`) and `"^ Years"` (Group 1 empty). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ka983V/1)

Comment: in user's question - I clearly see 2(two) patterns "N to M Years" and "N-M Years", so I think your example does not match with user's example as it is presented

Comment: My point is simply that your regex will match really bad data.

Comment: so far, it will match whatever data described in the user's question! Obviously, if user's real data is different from what is presented in the question  - it will not work! On that - I agree with you! :o)